# Internet Explorer does not load images cross domain (https)

Tags: image, internet-explorer, https, cross-domain

this is an updated question:
I am trying to include a picture on an external server.

PROBLEM HERE: my home website is using https:// and the picture on the external server is just http. The picture is fine (tested) but IE seems not to allow to access http:// sources when on a https:// website.

I am looking for html or javascript code to allow access for loading pictures from other domain WHEN my home domain is HTTPS and my external domain is HTTP

thanks
Klaus

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is a feature of the browser. When you enter a page like this on IE and some other browsers, it will give the user the option to disallow "unsecured" elements on the page (this includes elements served over HTTP); and will not display them. Your page cannot override the users' action.